# 503 Service Unavailable Error from a service

Tags: rest, cloud, microservices

I have microservices in the cloud and within my service which is running on kubernetes. I am making a request to another service. Everything was working for a long time but suddenly I started to get 503 Service Unavailable error. But when we check other service logs, I see that my request  did not arrive there at all.

Increasing the memory of service which makes request to another service solves the issue. But still I do not know what can be the problem and how can I figure it out.

Comment: Kindly explain your question like what type of service, where it is hosted also post your code then only we can help you.

Comment: Service is running on kubernetes. Actually everthing was running. But after a time later, I got this error. Increasing memory of the service who makes request solved the issue now. But I do not know what can be reason